# A RegExp pattern to find a number separated with hyphens

Tags: regex, vba

I would like to find a number separated into 3 parts with 2 hyphens. Each part does not have a set number of figures so for example "123-12-12222" , "1-2303-11" "45456874-1-258" are all good. Any suggestions for a RegExp pattern? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this is fine for you:

```
\d+-\d+-\d+
```

3 sequences of 0-many digits, separated by `-`s

[RegExr Example](http://regexr.com?37c1n) matching the numbers in your post.

Answer (score 0):

line = `"123-12-12222"` for ex.

```
match = Regex.Match(line, @"(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)",RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

the parenthese are used to grab the actual digits between the hyphens so you can reference them as such

```
a=match.Groups[0].Value;
b=match.Groups[1].Value;
c=match.Groups[2].Value;
```